# Static property inheritance not working as expected

Tags: typescript, browserify, visual-studio-code, tsify

I have something like this;

**TestBase.ts**

```
export class TestBase {
    static myValue: boolean;
    constructor() {
        TestBase.myValue = true;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
import {TestBase} from './TestBase'

export class Test extends TestBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**SomeOtherClass.ts**

```
import {Test} from './Test';
import {TestBase} from './TestBase';

export class SomeOtherClass {
    constructor() {
        var test = new Test();
        console.log(Test.myValue); // undefined
        Test.myValue = false;
        console.log(Test.myValue, TestBase.myValue); // false, true
    }
}
```

My IDE is suggesting that `myValue` is available on `Test`, but at runtime it does not reflect the value of `TestBase.myValue`.  Is the IDE incorrectly suggesting that static property inheritance is allowed, or is browserify/tsify breaking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Typescript, static primitives are not inherited in the way I was expecting, however static objects are.  I was able to work around the issue by holding the value inside an object;

**TestBase.ts**

```
export class TestBase {
    static someObject = { myValue: boolean };
    constructor() {
        TestBase.someObject.myValue = true;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
import {TestBase} from './TestBase'

export class Test extends TestBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**SomeOtherClass.ts**

```
import {Test} from './Test';
import {TestBase} from './TestBase';

export class SomeOtherClass {
    constructor() {
        var test = new Test();
        console.log(Test.someObject.myValue); // true
        Test.myValue = false;
        console.log(Test.someObject.myValue, TestBase.someObject.myValue); // false, false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is related to typescript, and your IDE is correct. Static members are inherited ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#823-inheritance-and-overriding)). I have tried your sample in node.js environment as well as in chrome browser and it outputs

> true
>
> false, true

as expected. So I guess you are correct assuming something else messing up things, maybe browserify.

Comment: If the property is static, isn't the second line's output expected to be `true,  true`?

Comment: Not in Typescript, due to how it is compiled in javascript (es5 - using prototypes, and es6 - classes). One more observation I noticed: in my tests above i was targeting ES6, but if I target ES5 (for example run code in typescript playground) - I will get the 'undefined' in output as you did. So I would say its a discrepancy between compilation to ES5 and ES6, maybe bug?

Comment: In that case, isn't the IDE incorrect, considering the property should not be available on the child class?

Comment: I think that according to the specs the property should be in child class as it is inherited (although static inheritance behaves differently from C#) - so IDE is correct. The only misbehavior I see is the 'undefined' vs 'true' when compiled for the different targets.

Comment: "static inheritance behaves differently from c#" - I think that is what i'm missing here.  Can you point out a link that describes this, or a section of the spec?

Comment: I have not found explicit specification of this in specs (would be glad if someone points this out), but in the spec link I have provided it explicitly says - all members are inherited including static ones (unlike C# where static members are not inherited). Taking into account this (and looking into compiled js:)) we can justify behavior you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestBase {
    static myValue: boolean;
    constructor() {
        TestBase.myValue = true;
    }
}

class Test extends TestBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    constructor() {
        var test = new Test();
        console.log(Test.myValue); // undefined
        Test.myValue = false;
        console.log(Test.myValue, TestBase.myValue); // false, true
    }
}

class HelloWorld{
    public static main(){
        let some = new SomeOtherClass();
    }
}
HelloWorld.main();
```

I think it is undefined because only initialized when the constructor is called, for that class.

Change by this.

```
class TestBase {
        static myValue: boolean = true;
        constructor() {
            TestBase.myValue = true;
        }
    }
```

---

```
        console.log(Test.myValue); // true
        Test.myValue = false;
        console.log(Test.myValue, TestBase.myValue); // false, true
```

you probably already know, but you do not need to build an object to call a static member.

At first time, `Test.myValue` and `TestBase.myValue` is undefined, when you build an object `var test = new Test();`. That happens to be true for that class `TestBase` change in `constructor`, `TestBase.myValue = true;`, but not for Test, because you access Test.myValue statically or TestBase.myValue, and `TestBase.myValue` after creating the object to be changed but not in `Test`.

Applied to the original code:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    constructor() {

        console.log(Test.myValue);     // undefined
        console.log(TestBase.myValue); // undefined

        var test = new Test();

        console.log(Test.myValue);     // undefined
        console.log(TestBase.myValue); // true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You simply cannot inherit static properties or methods.

Comment: I think that's not true, if not why he can do Test.myValue?, when myValue is declared in TestBase.

Comment: I'm not sure what ide he uses, but it should fail compilation. Because static property compiles to nothing actually. The property sits on the function `TestBase` itself and not on its prototype so there is no inheritance

Answer (score -2):

It's class level properties trying as member level instance won't work. We need declare as member instance and initialize as member instance instead class object

```
export class TestBase {
    static myValue: boolean;
    constructor() {
        this.myValue = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Accessing a `static` value using `this` is not valid Typescript.